# How to compute the expected stock price from option prices?

Tags: options

I need to extract expected future stock price from an option price. Could anyone please suggest me how I could do this?

Comment: Call-put parity if these options are European

Comment: If the expected future price is anything other than the current price + risk-free interest, something is wrong. If you're looking for a range of possible future prices (whose mean and median will be current price + risk-free interest), fit the near-the-money options to the Black Scholes equation to compute volatility.

Answer (score 1):

If by "expected future stock price" you mean the stock's "forward price" for a given maturity (eg 1 year forward), F, then look at the price of all puts and all calls for this maturity, find the strike K such as the price of the put for this strike equals the price of the call for the same strike, C(K) = P(K), and K should be the forward stock price you are looking for, F = K. This comes from the [Put-Call parity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Put%E2%80%93call_parity).

Answer (score 1):

As Janthelme said the Put-Call Parity is the best approach. Nevertheless if you have enough Information you can also use the Interest Rate and the Dividend Yield to come up with an expected Future Stock level.

But remarkt the convexity of an option. Hence the todays premium is not equal the discounted value of E[S]-K.